# How would I parse a filename from a location I grab from a table before it's bound to the dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, drop-down-menu

So in one of my tables, there lies an image file location. I'm grabbing that information to be displayed in an asp:dropdownlist, however, I want just the name of the image to be displayed. How/Where would I parse the filename out of it. Also, is there a built in method for grabbing the filename?

EDIT::

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397663.aspx

instead of:

```
var oData = from c in oDb.CustomerImages
                    where c.CustomerID == CustomerID         &&
                          c.CustomerNumber == CustomerNumber &&
                          c.CategoryID == CategoryID
                    orderby c.ID
                    select new { Path.GetFileName(c.Location), c.ID };
```

just set it to a variable, and then set you set your dropdownlist.DataTextField = to that variable's name:

solution:

```
var oData = from c in oDb.CustomerImages
                    where c.CustomerID == CustomerID         &&
                          c.CustomerNumber == CustomerNumber &&
                          c.CategoryID == CategoryID
                    orderby c.ID
                    select new { Location = Path.GetFileName(c.Location), c.ID };

        return oData;

//elsewhere  ...

dropdownlist.DataTextField = "Location";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use

[Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx)

> Returns the file name and extension of
>   the specified path string.

Comment: Ah ok cool. But where exactly do I edit the data I grab from my table? At the end of my SQL statement ------- select new { Path.GetFileName(c.Location), c.ID }; That doesn't work

Comment: I've figured it out, update in OP. Thanks for the Path.GetFileName()

Answer (score 1):

There's a Path class that has lots of useful methods.